# Joomla 4: Problem with the contact form, the text sent is missing

Tags: joomla-4.x, emails, joomla-4, contact-form, cassiopeia

I'm creating a contact form with Privacy Check box (Joomla 4, template Cassiopeia).
I have done all the steps as in joomla 3.x (custom fields) and everything works. But...
When the e-mail arrives, all the data and the text written in the box are missing!

I did some tests:

- 2 different hosting;
- 3 different websites (all Joomla 4, Cassiopeia template);
- 2 websites with the check box and 1 without check box.

Same problem for all websites: I don't see the text that is written in the box (and the data of who sent the message).

Any suggestions of what I need to check?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].  Please also [edit] your question to include the debugging details requested by Lodder?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The problem is in the Italian language on administrator backend (I presume).
Tested with the English language it works (but only if the English language remains!).

Comment: I am curious about what exactly was wrong with the italian pack.  Did you discover any other details/clues?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in french, in fact I had an old version of french language. I have re installed the french language and the problem is now solved.